# Cocos2D retina display

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am following this tutorial to use OpenGLES shaders in Cocos2D.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10862/how-to-create-cool-effects-with-custom-shaders-in-opengl-es-2-0-and-cocos2d-2-x

When I run my code on simulator for retina or on my iPhone4, these three effects only hold 1/4 of the screen.
But when I run the tutorial sample code(download from the tutorial), it displays correctly with fullscreen.
My Cocos2D is 2.02. I'm sure My code is as same as the sample code.
I wonder if it is because I use newer version Cocos2D lib than the lib in the tutorial sample code?
How to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out ...
In AppDelegate.m
comment
if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )

Answer (score 0):

The example is certainly provided without the retina assets (-hd extension). Thus if you activate the retina display ([director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES]), the SD assets are considered to be HD assets, and appear half size.